# Opening the Android USB Settings menu with an intent

Tags: android

I want to open the "USB computer connection" settings menu from within an Android app.  Looking at the logcat output from another app that does this, I found that what I want to do can be done from an ADB shell with

```
am start -n com.android.settings/.UsbSettings
```

How do I do the same thing from within an Android app?  I know that you can do things like

`startActivity(new Intent(Settings.whatever));`

but there isn't a "whatever" for the USB settings menu.

Answer (score 1):

The solution ended up being to use an explicit intent:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.UsbSettings"));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Some devices don't have this component, so remember to wrap in a try/catch. Also, this crashes the Settings app on Google Pixel with an error of `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid fragment for this activity`. I wonder why there's no Settings.ACTION for this.

Comment: from OREO you need "android.permission.MANAGE_USB" which requires root